# How can I add a word to each element of the array in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

I did in Zsh:

```
array={geometry, analysis, topology, graph theory, calculus}
echo $array
```

and then I wanted to add word "math:" to each element like" math:calculus":

```
while (( i++ < 10)); { echo math:$array[i] }
```

But it does not work? Why?

Comment: um, are you sure this is ZSH?  That doesn't look like the correct list initialization syntax to me...

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me in zsh with the assignment changed from:

```
array={geometry, analysis, topology, graph theory, calculus}
```

to

```
array=(geometry, analysis, topology, graph theory, calculus)
```

But zsh has tons of options that change its behavior.  Maybe the output 'setopt' might help.

Comment: Also , make sure you reinitialize i to 0 each time you run it

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
array=(geometry analysis topology "graph theory" calculus)
print -l math:${^array}
```

or check `RC_EXPAND_PARAM` for the `${^var}` form.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I'm going to go out on a limb here (because I don't accept that the supporting code is correct) and say that "echo math:$array[i]" is missing a dollar sign and should be "echo math:$array[$i]"

Comment: With mine the i doesn't need the dollar sign.

Comment: well, at least I was right about the initialization being wonky.  The ZSH example I looked at used the dollar sigil when referencing the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through an array works better with `for` because you won't over run the end like your code will (unless you set your limit to the size of the array with ${#array[*]}).

Also, I assume you don't want the commas to be included as part of the strings and you should use parentheses instead of curly braces for your array.

```
array=(geometry analysis topology "graph theory" calculus)
for i in $array; do echo math:$i; done
```